# What glass piece is this?

Tags: part-identification

Does anyone know what this is?There is no identifier number, just 2-01.[image]

Answer (score 14):

This is part 2060 - Windscreen 4 x 4 x 3 Canopy in Trans Black (Smoke)

[image]

Image from [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2620&name=Windscreen%204%20x%204%20x%203%20Canopy&category=%5BWindscreen%5D#T=C)

The part in that colour is only available in the [Star Wars Slave I](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7144-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

Comment: Great, that is what I was looking for! Thanks for your help!